# Delete specific rows in Oracle Database using SAS table

Tags: sql, oracle, sas

I have a Oracle table with 1M rows in it. I have a subset of oracle table in SAS with 3000 rows in it. I want to delete these 3000 rows from the oracle table.

```
Oracle Table columns are
Col1    Col2    Col3    timestamp

SAS Table columns are:
Col1    Col2    Col3
```

The only additional column that Oracle table has is a timestamp. This is the code that I using currently, but it's taking a lot of time.

```
libname  ora oracle user='xxx' password='ppp' path = abcd;
PROC SQL; 
DELETE from ora.oracle_table a
where exists (select * from sas_table b where a.col1=B.col1 AND a.col2=B.col2 AND A.col3=B.col3 ); 
QUIT;
```

Please advise as to how to make it faster and more efficient.

Thank You !

Comment: Do the tables have a primary key?

Comment: no. The three columns combined makes a primary key.

Comment: is there a joint index on col1, 2 and 3 in Oracle?

Comment: there is a joint index in Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to push your SAS table up to Oracle, then use oracle-side commands to perform the delete.  I'm not sure exactly how SAS will translate the above code to DBMS-specific code, but it might be pushing a lot of data over the network depending on how it's able to optimize the query; in particular, if it has to perform the join locally instead of on the database, that's going to be very expensive.  Further, Oracle can probably do the delete faster using entirely native operations.

IE:

```
libname ora ... ;

data ora.gtt_tableb;  *or create a temporary or GT table in Oracle and insert into it via proc sql;
set sas_tableb;
run;

proc sql;
 connect to oracle (... );
 execute (
  delete from ... 
  ) by connection to oracle;
quit;
```

That may offer significant performance improvements over using the LIBNAME connection.

Further improvements may be possible if you take full advantage of an index on your PKs, if you don't already have that.

Answer (score 1):

@Joe has a good answer.  Another way would be to do something like this.  This MIGHT allow the libname engine to pass all the work to Oracle instead of retrieving rows back to SAS (which is where your time is going).

Created some test data to show

```
data test1 test2;
do i=1 to 10;
 do j=1 to 10;
  do k=1 to 10;
   output;
  end;
 end;
end;
run;

data todel;
do i=1 to 3;
 do j=1 to 3;
  do k=1 to 3;
   output;
  end;
 end;
end;
run;

proc sql noprint;
delete from test1 as a
where a.i in (select distinct i from todel)
  and a.j in (select distinct j from todel)
  and a.k in (select distinct k from todel);
quit;

proc sql noprint;
delete from test2 as a
where exists (select * from todel as b where a.i=b.i and a.j=b.j and a.k=b.k);
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys. Joe I used your suggestion and wrote this code.

```
 /*---create a temp table in oracle---*/
       libname  ora oracle user='xxx' password='ppp' path = abcd;
        proc append base=ora.TEMP_TABLE data=SAS.sas_TABLE;
        run;

        /*-----delete the rows using the temp table--------*/
        proc sql;
         connect to oracle(......);
         execute (delete from ORA.ORACLE_TABLE a
          where exists (select * from ora.TEMP_TABLE b where a.col1=B.col1 AND a.col2=B.col2 AND A.col3=B.col3)
        ) by oracle;
        quit;
```

Thank you so much guys ! I appreciate your feedback.